# What happens to connections when there are more than max_connections?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have set `max_connections=10` in my `postgresql.conf` and make 11 concurrent connections. What happens with the 11-nth connection?

Will it be refused with an error or will it wait until some connection slots free up?

If exceeding connections wait in queue, is there a timeout limit for them? Where can that be set? Is it a fair queue?

Is there any documentation on this? I can't find this in the official docs

--------- edit ----------

found a source on this (no connection pooling): https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections

> The decision not to include a connection pooler inside the PostgreSQL server itself has been taken deliberately and with good reason:

Comment: You will get an error, there is no queue. Why don't you try for yourself, this is easy to test.

Comment: Is this behavior documented somewhere? I need a reference to docs on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html)

> max_connections (integer)
>
> Determines the maximum number of concurrent
>   connections to the database server. The default is typically 100
>   connections, but might be less if your kernel settings will not
>   support it (as determined during initdb). This parameter can only be
>   set at server start.

In combination with the name of the variable it should be clear what happens: If you try to open up more than the number of set connections, you will get an error. In this case you will get a very prominent error that the number of connections is exhausted.

Postgres itself is not including any connection pooling or similar so it's either "Yes, you got in" or "No, you are not".